# Is there a function on Databricks that allows displaying an R data frame interactively similarly to Spark's display()?

Tags: r, apache-spark, databricks

On Databricks, data frames, whether created with Python, SQL, SparkR or PySpark, can be nicely and interactively displayed using the `display(df)` function. However, an R data frame from base R cannot be displayed using the latter function. I tried using `View` but it could not display the data frame and I can only display it using `head` or `tail`. Are there any Databricks-native methods to display R data frames?

For the sake of a reproducible example, I am trying to display these two data frames:

```
%python
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
df = pd.DataFrame(np.array([[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]]), columns = ['a', 'b', 'c'])
display(df)
```

```
%r
df <- data.frame(a = c(1,4,7), b = c(2,5,7), c = c(3,6,9))
head(df)
```

Attached are two screenshots: one for the function `display` I refer to on Databricks that displays a data frame interactively and nicely, and the other is displaying R data frames.

[image: Displaying data frames in python on Databricks]
[image: Displaying head of data frames in R on Databricks]

Comment: The class `data.frame` has print methods. There is no class named Data.Frame in base methods. Your data structure provably needs a particular package that has defined functions for that class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After doing some research, along the way I found that the R library `data.table` is much more efficient in handling large datasets and can be used to print data frames nicely in Databricks. It still has limitations on the size of the data that can be printed which is less than the limit on Python data frames display, but it allows scrolling up and down and seeing head and tail of data frames.

**Note** that both of the print functions below can work with base R data frames and `data.table` data frames. `data.table` is only referred to here for efficiency purposes and/or concerns.

```
# Attach data.table library after installing it -- install.packages("data.table")
# or install it through the cluster's libraries: 
library(data.table)

# Adding more data to my previous R df:
df <- data.frame(a = c(0:1200), b = seq(0, 12000, by = 10), c = seq(0, 600, by=0.5))
# Convert the base R data frame into a data.table data frame: 
dt <- setDT(df)
```

Now comes the fun part; displaying the data frame. If a data frame is of a `data.table` class or type, then `data.table` has a couple of options for displaying the data frame:

**Using print()**

```
print(dt)
```

Result:

[image]

Or,

**Using print.AsIs()**

```
print.AsIs(dt)
```

Result:

[image]

The latter allows you to scroll through the whole data table, but similarly to `display`, it has a limit on the number of entries to be shown if the table has a very large size.